# Windows phone custom textbox - no SIP / remove contents only

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am designing a simple calculator app.

There, I have my own keyboard(bunch of buttons) to input stuff. So, I don't need system keyboard for input.
But, I want user to be able to select and delete contents from expression box just like a normal textbox.

Is this possible? I don't think it will be; considering tight restrictions on APIs from Microsoft. But, still taking a shot in the dark..

Comment: Do you need to programmatically delete contents? Or for the user to delete the contents?

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible but you'll have to simulate a number of things that the native controls give you such as focus, and text selection.

For the sake of adding partial selection of text this seems unnecessarily complicated. If you really must have partial selection, I'd suggest trying virtual arrow keys to move the caret along the selection.